# Персистентный двухсвязный список

Tags: список, структуры-данных, двусвязный-список

Интересует реализация персистентного двухсвязного списка.

На википедии находил формальное описание метода, который заключается в комбинировании методов копирования пути и "толстых" узлов. Но мне допустим не совсем понятно, как это эффективно написать на языке программирования. Также возникают вопрос, какие функции будут доступны в такой реализации.

Меня бы интересовал список с функциями pop_front() и pop_back().

Не мог ли бы кто-то дать рекомендации насчет реализации или ещё лучше - пример кода на любом из языков программирования.

Answer (score 0):

В чем проблема реализовать это с помощью алгоритмов, которые использует гит, а именно, создать очередь и в ней хранить объект описывающий, что у вас изменилось в списке и как вернуться назад. 
Такая структура данных, легко восстанавливает предыдущее значение и легко дорабатывается до вида, когда свободно можно переходить от одной версии к другой